# Regex return everything but compound expression

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to parse a gcode program to return everything except the comments contained withing ().  The non-negated version works: ([(].*[)]) to return the comments ONLY.  Why doesn't the pattern below return everything EXCEPT the comments?:

```
(?!([(].*[)]))

%
O1000
T1 M6
G0 G90 G40 G21 G17 G94 G80
G54 X-75 Y-25 S500 M3  (Start Point)
G43 Z100 H1
Z5
G1 Z-20 F100
X-50 M8               (Position 1)
Y0                    (Position 2)
X0 Y50                (Position 3)
X50 Y0                (Position 4)
X0 Y-50               (Position 5)
X-50 Y0               (Position 6)
Y25                   (Position 7)
X-75                  (Position 8)
G0 Z100
M30
%
```

Comment: A comment is like (Position 1).  the flavour is regex101.com for now then into python.
I've read other comments that its good practice to use the host facility (language, command etc) to do the negation of the overall expression.  I'm using python so I think I will do this in steps because i want to do multiple exclusions.  Like strip spaces after I strip comments.  Then other weird gcode things like block numbers etc

Comment: What are you doing, matching line's? Do you want to match _up to_ but not after or what ?? Just replace all of the _comments_ with nothing.. problem solved.

Comment: If you're doing some exotic thing, you have to actually match _comments_ to move the match position past it. I hope you understand that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of notes on your regex: `(?![(].*[)])` matches an empty space that is not followed with `(`, any 0+ chars other than a newline, up to the last `)` on the line. So, you only have a zero length match - no wonder you do not get anything.

If comments are the last `(...)` on a line, and they cannot have parentheses inside, use `re.sub` with

```
r'(?m)\s*\([^()]*\)[ \t]*$'
```

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iD4sC1/2). Replace with an empty string.

**Pattern details**:

- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `\(` - an opening `(`
- `[^()]*` - zero or more characters other than `(` and `)`
- `\)` - a closing `)`
- `[ \t]*` - zero or more spaces or tabs (you may replace with `[^\S\r\n]`)
- `$` - end of line (since `(?m)` (=`re.MULTILINE`)  is used).

[Python demo](http://ideone.com/EbCcir):

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'\s*\([^()]*\)[ \t]*$', re.MULTILINE)
s = "%\nO1000\nT1 M6\nG0 G90 G40 G21 G17 G94 G80\nG54 X-75 Y-25 S500 M3  (Start Point)\nG43 Z100 H1\nZ5\nG1 Z-20 F100\nX-50 M8               (Position 1)\nY0                    (Position 2)\nX0 Y50                (Position 3)\nX50 Y0                (Position 4)\nX0 Y-50               (Position 5)\nX-50 Y0               (Position 6)\nY25                   (Position 7)\nX-75                  (Position 8)\nG0 Z100\nM30\n%"
result = p.sub("", s)
print(result)
```

Comment: Thx that did the trick.  Although I have another optional step for removing all spaces and block numbers (not shown) from the program it makes senses not to leave dangling whitespace anyway.  BTW removing certain parts of a gcode program makes it transmit faster which helps with drip feeding to cnc machines in tape mode.

Answer (score 1):

Because a negative lookahead isn't used to negate an entire regex (meaning, it's not used to match the oppose of what the given regex is). It's used to say, at this point, assert that looking forward in the text it is not possible to match this regex.

A more simple example, we know that this is used to match all digits:

```
\d+
```

Well, to match everything that **isn't** a digit, we can't do this:

```
(?!\d+)
```

Because that doesn't do that. What that means, is at the current position of matching, make sure that looking ahead, we don't have digits. The actual negation of `\d` has its own character class:

```
\D+
```

Given your example code, you could use this regex to match everything that isn't a comment:

```
^[^(]+
```

[Try it](https://regex101.com/r/yI6nF9/1)

Comment: `^[^()]+` matches 1+ characters other than ( and ) from the beginning of a string - it does not *match everything that isn't within ()*

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - Understood, that's why I prefixed it with "Given your example code", because in the context of the OP's example, that is exactly what it matches.

Comment: @nickb -your pattern worked :) thx.  It returns a string stripped of comments.  However, it took me a minute to figure out that the m in /gm was important.

Comment: @dpetican: `^[^(]+` does not allow `(` in the data you have. If the data can have `(`, it is not clear how to define the boundaries of the comment (that also can have `(` and `)`). If the comments cannot have `(` and `)`, you can just use `re.sub(r'(?m)\([^()]*\)[ \t]*$', '', input)`.

Comment: Well it seems to work but.... It hurts my brain less to do the negation in python by deleting the match using sub() with "" as the replacement.  I'm doing several strip and replace operations in a row anyway.